# How to write PIG script to extract log lines between two given time stamps?

Tags: time, apache-pig

Need help in writing PIG script to extract log lines between two given time stamps.

Sample log file:

```
2016/08/17 09:00:00 This is log line 1<BR>
2016/08/17 09:05:00 This is log line 2<BR>
2016/08/17 10:00:00 This is log line 3<BR>
2016/08/18 09:00:00 This is log line 4<BR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is tab separated,load the log into two fields and use filter on the first field.

```
A = LOAD 'log.txt' using PigStorage('\t') AS (dt:datetime,line:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY (dt > '2016/08/17 09:00:00' AND dt < '2016/08/18 09:00:00');
DUMP B;
```

Using parameters

```
pig -f myscript.pig -param start_dt='2016/08/17 09:00:00' end_dt='2016/08/18 09:00:00'

A = LOAD 'log.txt' using PigStorage('\t') AS (dt:datetime,line:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY (dt > start_dt AND dt < end_dt);
DUMP B;
```